# How do i Mute the Output in Python while assigning a fuction?

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, youtube-api

I'm trying to use youtube_dl inside python script. But I want to prevent the below from being printed.

```
[youtube] YQHsXMglC9A: Downloading webpage
```

In diffrent questions i saw the usage of stdout and here is my code with it.

```
import io,sys
print("get")
tempp=io.StringIO()
sys.stdout=tempp
ydl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL({'outtmpl': '%(id)s%(ext)s'})
with ydl:
    result = ydl.extract_info(url,download=False)
if 'entries' in result:
    video = result['entries'][0]
else:
    video = result
sys.stdout=sys.__stdout__
title=video['title']
result=[]
video_url = video['formats']
for i in video_url:
    if i['ext']=='mp4':
        formatted=i['format'][(i['format']).index('(')+1:(i['format']).index(')')]
        result.append({'format':formatted,'url':i['url']})
for i in range(0,len(result)):
    print(i+1,'>',result[i]['format'])
```

But its usage doesnt allow assigning to the variable "video". So how do i mute the output of the assigning function?

Comment: Not sure to understand: where do you get your line printed? So far I don't see why you'd have an output with the code you showed.

Comment: The command `result = ydl.extract_info(url,download=False)` shows that output in the first code block while assigning to the variable `result`.I want to run that asignment muted.

Comment: In the available options in the source they say there's a `quiet` option. Have you tried `ydl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL({'outtmpl': '%(id)s%(ext)s', 'quiet': True})`?

Comment: @Axe319 that does work. But this is an example. What about other assignments of a functions?

Comment: In your example you say `But its usage doesn't allow assigning to the variable "video"` What makes you think that? Put a `print(video)` after your line `sys.stdout=sys.__stdout__` and you'll see that it does in fact do that.

Comment: @Axe319 after that i have: `for i in video_url:
            if i['ext']=='mp4':
                formatted=i['format'][(i['format']).index('(')+1:(i['format']).index(')')]
                result.append({'format':formatted,'url':i['url']})
        for i in range(0,len(result)):
            print(i+1,'>',result[i]['format'])` and it doesnt work

Comment: What's in `video_url`? You're assigning your result to `video`. Please include the amount of code it takes to you reproduce your issue so we can run it ourselves without making any guesses.

Comment: @Axe319 i'll add it in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210376/discussion-between-infinitytm-and-axe319).

Comment: Change this line to `formatted=i['format'][(i['format']).index('(')+1:(i['format']).index(')')]`. You were missing an `i`.

Comment: @Axe319 that was an error during copying the code